# Segmentation fault when importing module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, segmentation-fault, natty

I have a Python script that uses natural language date parser [Natty](https://github.com/eadmundo/python-natty). Natty itself is written in Java but wrapped for its use in Python using Jpype. The script works perfectly fine on my development machine but throws an segmentation fault on the production machine:

```
>>> import natty
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

On *both* machines, using `pip freeze` I get the same version of relevant modules:

```
...
JPype==0.5.4.2
JPype1==0.6.1
...
natty==0.2.4
...
```

On *both* machine, I run the same Python versions

```
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.version)
2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

On *both* machines, `JAVA_HOME` is set to the same value

```
>echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

In short, I cannot spot any obvious differences. I found this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654449/error-segmentation-fault-core-dumped) that lists causes for segmentation faults, but it didn't really help me. I kind of assume that it's a Java code wrapped using Jpype, but that's just a guess.

How can I hunt down that error?

**EDIT:** `gdb python` gives me the following out put

```
(gdb) run ~/tmp/natty-test.py
Starting program: /usr/bin/python ~/tmp/natty-test.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe48bf2b4 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007fffe48bf2b4 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000246 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fffe48bf160 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007ffff5901990 in VM_Operation::_names ()
   from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fffffffcf90 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007ffff543168d in VM_Version::get_processor_features() ()
   from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

`natty-test.py` only contains `import natty`

Comment: Check for dependencies installed are same on development and production.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Natty (python package) has only two dependencies, `JPype1` and `python-dateutil`. Both are the same and the latest versions on both machines. Or do you refer the the Natty JAR file? When I check [https://github.com/joestelmach/natty/blob/master/pom.xml](https://github.com/joestelmach/natty/blob/master/pom.xml) I see a couple of dependencies, but I have no idea how to proceed with that.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** I had to update the Kernel of my Ubuntu installation on the production machine.

I noticed that Jpype already caused the problem

```
>>> import jpype  
>>> jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())  
Segmentation fault
```

Searching for this problem brought me to this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719488/segmentation-fault-when-starting-jvm-using-jpype) and the included link to an [AskUbuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927188/what-is-stack-clash-and-what-can-i-do-about-it/927190#927190). The kernel on the production machine was 4.4.0-81-generic, one if the kernels mentioned there. After the update to 4.10.0-32-generic all works fine now.